# How to apply a Kalman filter to use both previous and future measurements of a random variable?

Tags: regression, estimation, kalman-filter

I'm trying to estimate the state of a Gaussian random walk with central tendency based on time series measurements with varying uncertainties.  My random variable has the following form:

$ \frac{d x}{d t} \equiv F(t) - \alpha x $

Where F is a Gaussian random variable.  I've noticed that this problem is analogous to the velocity of a bubble experiencing Brownian motion.  (See for example, F. Reif, *Fundamentals of Statistical and Thermal Physics*, p. 565).  As a result of the $ -\alpha x $ term, the position has a central tendency (i.e. the variance does not become infinity as time approaches infinity).

Now, like any good physicist, I know that I cannot exactly measure the value $x$.  The best I can do is to measure it at time $ t_i $ within some uncertainty, $ \sigma_i $.  Using a Kalman filter, I can estimate the value of $x$ from several measurements.  Let's call that $ \hat x $.  The approach is as follows.  For each measurement, we compute:

> $ \delta t = t_i - t_{i-1} $
>
> $ P(t) = P(t_{i-1}) * e^{-\alpha\,  \delta t} + \langle x^2 | \delta t \rangle $
>
> $ K = {{P}\over{P + \sigma_i}} $
>
> Our incoming est estimate of $x_i$:
>
> $ \hat x_{i-} = \hat x_{i-1} \, e^{-\alpha\,\delta t} $
>
> $ \hat x_i = \hat x_{i-} + K [x_{obs} - \hat x_{i-}] $

This works great for propagating our estimates forward in time.  My question is: If I have measurements at times that span the time at which I want the best estimate, how do I compute an $\hat x(t) $ where $ t_i < t < t_{i+1} $?

Comment: I'm a bit confused, perhaps by the title. Are you wanting to interpolate between two time points or are you asking about something like smoothing (as opposed to filtering)?

Comment: @Wayne I'd like to interpolate between the two measurement times, but include information about the future measurement -- not just the previous measurements.

Comment: just to clarify, by `*` you mean the usual product or [convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution)?

Comment: @mpiktas product.  One of the hazards of copying from code.  :)  I've corrected the post for clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to me like a Kalman smoothing problem, which essentially computes the mean value of the state given past, present and future observations, with a computational effort similar to two Kalman filter passes. You might want to check any of the good books in existence which deal with the Kalman smoother, among them [Durbin-Koopman](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198523548) and [Anderson-Moore](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486439380).

Comment: Thanks.  I was hoping to see a worked example, but the right key words to search on was helpful.  I think I've found a good description.  Now to apply it.